# Unable to fetch html content in vercel server using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am working with Reactjs and using nextjs framework,Html content(description_front) is showing data fine in localhost
Here is api response (console)

```
Object
id: "55"
description_front: "<h3><strong>The crypto revolution and its effects</strong></h3>"
```

but whenever I am trying to display ,"html" content in server(vercel) via api, i am getting following data in my console,But whenever i am trying to display "description_front" in web page i am getting following error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description_front')
```

Here is my code, where i am wrong ?

```
import Axios from "axios";
import  {useRouter}  from "next/router";
const Post = ({ post }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const htmlString = post.description_front;
  return (
    <>
    <div className="product-des" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />
    <>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Try changing `const htmlString = post.description_front` to `const htmlString = post?.description_front`, as the data may be fetched after the page rendering completed

Comment: You don't show how `Post` is being used and how you're loading the data

Comment: @evolutionxbox: please check again, upated my question

Comment: The edit doesn't address my comment?

Comment: Please show us where the `post` data is getting fetched.

Answer (score -1):

When fetching data from localhost, the fetching is probably very quick, means that the data will be fetched even before the page render will be completed, and the original code will work as supposed.

But when fetching from a remote server, it takes more time, so the rendering process will be done before the data is fetched, and `post.description_front` will be null, what's causing this error.

The solution will be to check if the value is null before rendering, so a one liner will be: `const htmlString = post?.description_front` instead of `const htmlString = post.description_front`